# JTextpane does not save attributed text and icons in the file

Tags: java, swing

i was trying to save the Document of Java Text pane as "rtf" file 
the content of the Document is saved to the file but the attributes  like superscript and subscript and icons are not saved

`````
````java


     StyledDocument docx =(DefaultStyledDocument)  editor.getDocument();
     RTFEditorKit  kit = new RTFEditorKit();
     System.out.println(kit.getContentType()) ;
     int startPos = docx.getStartPosition().getOffset(); 
     int docLen = docx.getLength();
     File file = new File("E:\\file1.rtf");
     BufferedOutputStream out =null ;
     try {
          out=  new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
          kit.write(out, docx,startPos ,docLen);
          out.close();
     }      
     catch (Exception ex) {

     }

````
`````

Answer (score 0):

After Some reading i discovered that  java text package support for the RTF  file type is not complete , when  you write or read  the file using the TRFEditorkit   you get  a plain text .